# safari video frame changes on tabs change

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video, video-encoding

When we are viewing the video in Safari browser and let’s say we pause the video and change tabs, i.e. move to a different tab and come back to the video tab. The video frame changes and goes back a bit, i.e. suppose it was at frame 50 when paused, but when you come back it is around 35 or 40. Although when you check the currentTime it shows the current frame, i.e. frame 50. Has anyone faced this issue before ?

Video details -
Type - MP4
Data rate - 68kbps
Total bitrate - 100kbps
Frame rate - 24 frames/second
Bit rate -  32kbps
audio sample rate - 44khz